# Google play services "Unknown Error" signin

Tags: android, google-play-services

Summarize the bug:
Some users are reporting me that they cannot sign in and are receiving
"Unknown Error". I have modified BaseGameUtils to print the error code,
which in this case is 4.

Reproduction steps:
I can't reproduce the bug on any of my devices or friend's devices.

Describe the impact of this bug:
I cannot quantify how many can't sign in but i have got enough reports.

When did this bug start happening?
I think this bug exist since i have released the app.

How frequently does the bug occur?
The bug happens on some devices to some users with stock and non stock roms.

Describe any workarounds you have found:
No workaround found yet, i double checked the code, relinked the application,
contacted google for support (and they told me to get in touch via irc, but noone was able to help me),
watched the top 7 mistakes video and everything was fine, i mean on my devices there is no problem.

Problem Solved:
I changed the app id in the string file and was using an old linked id...
Remember to double, triple check everything.